# Open running instance of matlab

Tags: bash, matlab, cluster-computing

I am running a MATLAB script at a cluster, having used the command

```
matlab -nodisplay <LocalVariation.m
```

I can now see that it is not going to finish within the wall time I have put. Is there any way that after I have ssh'ed to the node, that I can open up the running MATLAB instance, and stop it within the program, such that I get access to the variables it has produced so far?

Comment: You can use the command line interface of MATLAB or is it a background proces?

Comment: Right now it is a background process, and then I want to open the command line interface for it.

Comment: [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266433/bring-process-to-foreground) or the duplicate may be useful.

Comment: I might have said too much above. It is not a background process in the sense that it can be retrieved by `fg` (or was put there with `bg`). It is just showing up, when I issue `top`, but otherwise I cannot find it.

Comment: Does the cluster use SLURM workload manager?

Comment: Yes, it does use slurm

Comment: @NickyMattsson, then the given answer should work!

Comment: I am sorry that I have not been faster to reply. However, I intended to ask how to do it if you had not already inserted a checkpoint and ran it using sbatch. In other a way to save the data in case I screwed up and miscalculated the time needed.

Comment: You can always ask nicely the sysadmin to increase the max wall time of your job as a one-time exceptional favour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Matlab does not allow that unless you explicitly include it beforehand in your Matlab script. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35183020/how-to-attach-to-a-running-matlab-script) for instance.

Also it is always good to [make your script 'checkpointable'](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=5343) so that you are able to restart easily from where the script was stopped.

Finally, a word about Octave, which has the option to [create a dump of the variables automatically](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Saving-Data-on-Unexpected-Exits.html) upon wrongful termination of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the SLURM workload manager you can try the following.

First open an interactive bash session using `srun --pty bash -i`. If you check your job queue using,`squeue -u <username>` you should find a bash session:

[image: squeue bash]

Now run your Matlab code with a breakpoint where you wish to stop execution. For example, a file `runTestJob.m` could look something like:

```
function runTestJob

   A = rand(5);
   B = randn(5);

   keyboard; % add breakpoint 
end
```

Now run code,

```
srun matlab -nodisplay -singleCompThread -r "runTestJob;quit"
```

This should give you a Matlab access directly in the terminal, so that you can use Matlab just like you would use it in the command window:

[image: matlab in terminal]

After you are done, make sure to close the interactive session and free up resources:

```
scancel <JOBID>
```

Hope that helps!